# org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Struct schemas do not match

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Trying to create and populate an array schema of type string inside an array schema of particular object type using kafka.connect.data.Schema in java. But getting error

> org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Struct schemas do not match.
>       at org.apache.kafka.connect.data.ConnectSchema.validateValue(ConnectSchema.java:239)
>       at org.apache.kafka.connect.data.ConnectSchema.validateValue(ConnectSchema.java:245)
>       at org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Struct.put(Struct.java:215)
>       at org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Struct.put(Struct.java:204)
>       at com.sintec.ra.fixture.BookProgramFixture.createAiringStruct(BookProgramFixture.java:60)
>       at com.sintec.ra.handlers.BookProgramTopicHandlerTest.mockAiringStruct(BookProgramTopicHandlerTest.java:132)
>       at com.sintec.ra.handlers.BookProgramTopicHandlerTest.init(BookProgramTopicHandlerTest.java:107)
>       at com.sintec.ra.handlers.BookProgramTopicHandlerTest.(BookProgramTopicHandlerTest.java:76)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>       at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:217)
>       at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:266)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>       at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:263)
>       at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
>       at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:538)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)
>   Eg

```
"airingTo" : [ {
      "dow" : [ "SATURDAY" ]
      }]
```

---

```
public static Struct createAiringStruct() 
{
    Schema valueSchema = createValueSchemaForProgram();
    Struct valueStruct = new Struct(valueSchema).put("airingTo", 
    getAiringList());
    return valueStruct;
}

private static Schema createValueSchemaForProgram() 
{
    return 
    SchemaBuilder.struct().name("PROGRAM").field("airingTo", 
    SchemaBuilder.array(createAiringListSchema())).build();
}

private static Schema createAiringListSchema() 
{
   return SchemaBuilder.struct().name("airingTo").field("dow", 
   SchemaBuilder.array(Schema.STRING_SCHEMA)).build();
}

private static List<Struct> getAiringList() 
{
    Struct valueStruct = new 
    Struct(createAiringListSchema()).put("dow", 
    Arrays.asList("SATURDAY"));
    List<Struct> dayPartList = new ArrayList<>();
    dayPartList.add(valueStruct);
    return dayPartList;
}
```

Comment: It would be easier to investigate if you add whole stack trace to your question

Comment: Sure let me put.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure where you got `.name("PROGRAM")`, but this seems to work for me.

It seems you were mixing struct names with fields.

```
    Schema dowSchema = SchemaBuilder.array(Schema.STRING_SCHEMA).build();
    Schema airingToItemSchema = SchemaBuilder.struct()
            .field("dow", dowSchema)
            .build();
    Schema airingToSchema = SchemaBuilder.array(airingToItemSchema).build();
    Schema rootSchema = SchemaBuilder.struct()
            .field("airingTo", airingToSchema);
            .build();

    Struct item = new Struct(airingToItemSchema)
            .put("dow", Collections.singletonList("SATURDAY"));
    Struct rootStruct = new Struct(rootSchema)
            .put("airingTo", Collections.singletonList(item));

    System.out.println(rootStruct);
```

Outputs

`Struct{airingTo=[Struct{dow=[SATURDAY]}]}`